# Custom Item Template Group

Tags: visual-studio, custom-controls

I'm building out custom item templates to work with our internal platform.  Is it possible to have these templates appear in their own group say "MyGroup" as opposed to being dropped into one of the other pre-existing groups?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you are deploying your custom item template, I've found two ways to do this.

1. If you are simply deploying the .zip file, you can [place it in a sub-folder in the appropriate language folder inside your ItemTemplates directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx#sectionToggle5).  For example:
   *\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C#\**MyGroup\myTemplate.zip***
2. If you are installing your custom template as part of a VSIX file, then open up the your .vsixmanifest file in the designer in Visual Studio, go to the "Content" section (at the bottom), and remove your Item Template.  Now, add it back using the "Add Content" button, and specify a "subfolder" (e.g. "MyGroup").  Now, when you install your extension, your Item Templates should show up inside a group with the same name as the specified sub-folder.